# Разница меду InstalledUICulture и CurrentUICulture

Tags: c#

Вопрос: если установлен другой языковой пакет для ОС, то `CurrentUICulture` какой даст результат? Установленный язык ОС или языкового пакета?

Нет возможности проверить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разница в том, что это совершенно разные вещи.

`CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture` содержит, понятно, системный язык. Он не меняется, очевидно. Его значение получается из вызова [`GetSystemDefaultUILanguage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318123(v=vs.85).aspx). Эта функция возвращает системный язык по умолчанию (то есть, язык, на котором система инсталлировалась), но не язык языковых пакетов.

`CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` — это текущий язык данного потока. Его можно установить в любое значение в любой момент.* Поэтому он имеет право меняться в течение пробега программы.

*Начальное значение* `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` равно `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` (если не `null`). Если там `null`, то берётся значение [`GetUserDefaultUILanguage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318137(v=vs.85).aspx) (не `GetSystemDefaultUILanguage`!).

Значение, возвращаемое `GetUserDefaultUILanguage`, равно выбранному языку текущего пользователя системы, если он установлен. Если нет, то текущему предпочитаемому языку системы. А если и его нет, то языку системы по умолчанию (то есть, языку, на котором система инсталлировалась).

Начальное значение `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` есть `null`, но вы можете поменять его в любой момент.

---

*Начиная с .NET 4.6. В более старых версиях фреймворка нужно было идти через `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`.

Comment: Я использую Framework 4.0. Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture как я понял - вернет ожидаемое?

Comment: @АлександрПузанов: Ну это смотря что вы ожидаете.

Comment: Установил языковой пакет, выбрал установленный язык и хочу, чтобы в качестве ожидаемого был не родной язык ОС, а именно установленный.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов: Тогда сохраните значение `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` при старте программы. Это и будет нужный вам язык.